# GridView linkbutton not causing external UpdatePanel to refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have an asp page with a regular panel that contains a gridview. The gridview has some linkbuttons that are used to generate a pdf.

I also have an UpdatePanel inside the regular panel and below the gridview that contains a label.

When the user clicks the 'generate' linkbutton inside the gridview, I want the label to say 'report generating' or something like that.

I have been unable to get this to work at all. I can throw values into the label all day long and nothing.

Here is the code for the panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ReportsPanel" runat="server" Height="611px">
    <h2>
        Reports
    </h2>
    <asp:Label ID="ReportsNotification" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Pharmacy: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="PharmaciesDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="PharmaciesDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="ListReportsGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
        GridLines="None" PageSize="10" CssClass="GridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        EmptyDataText="No rows for selection." OnRowCommand="ListReportsGridView_RowCommand"
        OnPageIndexChanging="ListReportsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
        EnablePersistedSelection="True"
        DataKeyNames="FinDataID">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAltRow" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewItem" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPager" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ControlStyle-CssClass="Hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hidden"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hidden" FooterStyle-CssClass="Hidden" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FinDataID" HeaderText="FinDataID" ControlStyle-CssClass="Hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hidden"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hidden" FooterStyle-CssClass="Hidden" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PeriodStart" HeaderText="Period Start" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PeriodEnd" HeaderText="Period End" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reports Available for Download"><ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonViewRpt" Text='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' CommandName="ViewRpt" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>    
            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false"><ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonGenerateRpt" Text='Generate' CommandName="GenerateRpt" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>    
            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false"><ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonUploadRpt" Text='Upload' CommandName="UploadRpt" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>    
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonGenerateRpt" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

I've tried with a button in the UpdatePanel, outside the UpdatePanel but neither of those ideas worked either. Surely this is possible!

The one thing I'm wondering, is when the 'generate' button fires and creates the pdf it is calling Response.End. I know this will end the thread and not reload the page. But I was hoping I could refresh the UpdatePanel *before* this happens... from what I can tell that's what UpdatePanel's are for, partial page updates.

Here is the code behind for the gridview:

```
protected void ListReportsGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (e.CommandName == "GenerateRpt")
    {//render pdf

        //populate empty report object with row information
        objFileData = new FileData();
        objFileData.PharmacyID = Convert.ToInt32(PharmaciesDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        objFileData.FinDataID = Convert.ToInt32(ListReportsGridView.Rows[intIndex].Cells[1].Text);
        objFileData.CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        objFileData.CreatedByID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
        objFileData.PeriodStart = Convert.ToDateTime(ListReportsGridView.Rows[intIndex].Cells[2].Text);

        lblMessage.Text = "Report generating...";
        //btnGenerate_Click(sender, e);
        RenderPdf();

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: And I'm also receiving this error...

A control with ID 'LinkButtonGenerateRpt' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Do I need to use the UniqueID or is scope otherwise an issue?

Comment: added a comment under the answer I added

Answer (score 4):

Your updatepanel `UpdateMode`  is conditional and you have to trigger the update yourself 
so when you need to update it you have to say `UpdatePanel1.Update();`

Comment: Good point. I was actually doing that in one of my button tests but forgot to put it back in after making a few other changes. Thanks! Also, please see the above edit for the error I'm currently receiving...

Comment: So did it fix your issue at last?

Comment: Well LinkButtonGenerateRpt is your button name but the point is your button will be created multiple times (once per row) therefore it will have different dynamic name each time so just remove the trigger from your updatepanel and update your panel as I mentioned using UpdatePanel1.Update();

Comment: Thanks again! I removed the trigger since I don't need both now. No errors and my code is being executed but I'm still not seeing the label text in the UpdatePanel... not sure what's going on now.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set a button that is in  a different naming container with the `updatepanel` as a  trigger. This is the reason why you get the error:*`A control with ID 'LinkButtonGenerateRpt' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1`*

If you really want the `Linkbutton` to be a trigger, you need to use [**`ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method, even Programmatically adding `AsyncPostBackTrigger` controls is NOT supported.

You could handle the GridView's `OnRowCreated` event and call [**`ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) for each LinkButton.Find out the control via findcontrol method.  Then in the linkbutton's `OnClick` event handler call `UpdatePanel.Update()` to get it to update.

GridView Markup ( only Linkbutton shown below ). Define an `OnClick` event for your link button.

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonGenerateRpt" Text='Generate' 
     CommandName="GenerateRpt" 
     CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" 
     OnClick="LinkButtonGenerateRpt_Click"runat="server">
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

// Grid View's RowCreated event. Here you Register the linkbuttons as asyncpostback triggers

```
protected void ListReportsGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    Control lnkBtnControl = e.Row.Cells[5].FindControl("LinkButtonGenerateRpt");
       if (lnkBtnControl!= null)
         {
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lnkBtnControl );
         }    
 }
```

And update the UpdatePanel on LinkButton click as:

```
protected void LinkButtonGenerateRpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            UpdatePanel1.Update();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @FlopScientist... I've tried that approach unfortunately the ScriptManager for this page is in the Site.Master page so I'm not getting a reference to it. If it's not one thing it's another!

Comment: I found this code that solved my ScriptManager issue:
    ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
However, now it's not calling RowCommand on the gridview when I click the other buttons and my DataBind on the gridview is failing due to invalid index after it finishes the RowCreated procedure...